# JS canvas getContext then transferControlToOffscreen

Tags: javascript, canvas

Working code:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var offscreen = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();
```

When using `.getContext()`:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var offscreen = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();
// InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
```

Further attempts do not work either:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
delete ctx;
var offscreen = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();
```

Or even so:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.reset();
delete ctx;
var offscreen = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();
```

Nothing changes with `webgl` instead of `2d`

So, how can i get the offscreen of a canvas which has something drawn on it, and then send it to a worker? Or must i use something like `getImageData()` and send the result alongside the offscreen of a brand new canvas, and let the worker copy with `putImageData()`? I do not want to make these additional operations (because will run slower).

Another way would have been to use `cloneNode()`, but the canvas image does not get copied.

Ive looked trough all methods of canvas and of context, but nothing seems to fix the problem.

I am using FF 67 with offscreen enabled. I suppose there is no difference in Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple: You cannot transfer control from a canvas that has a rendering context.

But you can:

```
const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(100, 1);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Wich is the same as doing:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var offscreen = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();
var ctx = offscreen.getContext('2d');
```

At the end of all you `transferToImageBitmap`:

```
var bitmap = offscreen.transferToImageBitmap();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, thanks. But in FF it throws `[Exception... "Method not implemented" nsresult: "0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)" location: "JS frame :: debugger eval code :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 3" data: no]`. I will try it on Chrome, and if i get it to work, ill select that as an answer

Comment: What browser are you using, etc?

Comment: FF 67, as ive noted in question

Comment: How did you enable the function as it is by default disabled? (I'm just confirming stuff). How about testing it on chromium  browser? Have you?

Comment: Everything is fine with Chrome, just FF, enabled trough `about:config`

Comment: It all points to poor implementation on firefox, and it seems they are not to exited about fixing it. You should edit your question: Maybe mention firefox on title and editing the last part that says "I suppose there is no difference in Chrome". You can follow status on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46800673/whats-the-state-of-offscreencanvass-support-for-2d-context). It seems tha Firefox implementation only works for `transferControlToOffscreen` but not with constructor `new OffscreenCanvas()`.